# Set video tag as background image and match the content

Tags: jquery, css

Here's my code:

```
.video-bg-container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
}

.video-bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    /*z-index: 9;*/
}

.video-bg-boxes {
    position: relative;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    /*top: 0;*/
    /*left: 0;*/
    /*right: 0;*/
    /*bottom: 0;*/
    padding: 70px 10%;
    z-index: 10;
}

.video-bg-boxes .blue-box {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #0091cf!important;
    padding: 30px 30px 80px 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Read full + demo at: https://jsfiddle.net/lanford/aeqx6ubp/4/

I want the video tag acts like an background image with back ground size cover: the width is always 100% but the height scale with the height of the contents inside and always responsive. Is there anyway to achive it by jquery or CSS?

Comment: I think this may better achieved using a canvas. What do you think?

Comment: I don't have any knowledge for canvas.

Comment: Check my answer..

Answer (score 1):

I think this might do the trick for you. But in this case on large devices the video will displayed properly with full width of the video visible. and the reason behind that is in most cases our video element aspect ratio will be different than our video source aspect ratio. So have used the `overflow:hidden`.One more thing that needs to be taken care of is to hide the video on mobile devices and just show a background image. This is because most mobile platforms won’t autoplay HTML5 video and will display it with an embedded play button on top of our content. And thats not an expected behaviour.

Remove width from video element. Keep `position:absolute;top:0;left:0` and give `overflow: hidden;` to `video-bg` class.

```css
.video-module {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.video-bg-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}

.video-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*z-index: 9;*/
}

video {
   position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.video-bg-boxes {
  position: relative;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  /*top: 0;*/
  /*left: 0;*/
  /*right: 0;*/
  /*bottom: 0;*/
  padding: 70px 10%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.video-bg-boxes .blue-box {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #0091cf!important;
  padding: 30px 30px 80px 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.video-bg-boxes .blue-box strong {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.video-bg-boxes .blue-box:hover {
  background-color: #E4E1E0!important;
  color: #4C4145!important;
}

.video-bg-boxes .blue-box:hover strong {
  color: #0091CF!important;
}

.video-bg-boxes .blue-box a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.video-bg-boxes .blue-box:hover a {
  color: #0091CF;
}

.video-bg-boxes .grey-box {
  border: none!important;
  padding: 30px 30px 80px 30px;
  background: url("https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3372283/axon-active/img/p1/blue-arrow-ico.png");
  background-position: center 90%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: #E4E1E0;
  color: #4C4145!important;
}

.video-bg-boxes .grey-box strong {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #0091CF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.video-bg-boxes .grey-box:hover {
  background: url("https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3372283/axon-active/img/p1/arrow-ico.png")!important;
  background-position: center 90%!important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
  background-color: #0091cf!important;
  color: #ffffff!important;
}

.video-bg-boxes .grey-box:hover strong {
  color: #ffffff!important;
}

.video-bg-boxes .grey-box a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4C4145;
}

.video-bg-boxes .grey-box:hover a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-module">
  <div class="video-bg-container">
    <div class="video-bg">
      <video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" controls="controls">
            <source src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3372283/axon-active/img/p1/VerseQuence%20-%20Wilt%20(VOEZ%20Official%20Soundtrack)%20-%20YouTube.mp4?t=1496825800724" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>

    <div class="video-bg-boxes">
      <div class="blue-box">
        <div style="text-align: center;"><strong>Title</strong></div>
        <div style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed condimentum enim eu finibus tincidunt. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent eget neque scelerisque, molestie turpis sed,
          tristique turpis. Proin placerat pretium libero, at pellentesque lorem condimentum eu.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="blue-box">
        <div style="text-align: center;"><strong>Title</strong></div>
        <div style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed condimentum enim eu finibus tincidunt. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent eget neque scelerisque, molestie turpis sed,
          tristique turpis. Proin placerat pretium libero, at pellentesque lorem condimentum eu.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="blue-box">
        <div style="text-align: center;"><strong>Title</strong></div>
        <div style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed condimentum enim eu finibus tincidunt. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent eget neque scelerisque, molestie turpis sed,
          tristique turpis. Proin placerat pretium libero, at pellentesque lorem condimentum eu.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/manishjanky/aeqx6ubp/5/)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: In big screen, the video is not full screen width.

Comment: do you want the video to be always on the screen with full width and height of screen? May if you elaborate a bit more on what you actually need i may be able to help better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `object-fit` get it

Update css

```
video {
  object-fit: cover;
  height:100vh;
  min-height:100%;
}
    body, html {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

```css
    body, html {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

video {
  object-fit: cover;
}

.video-module {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.video-bg-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}

.video-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /*z-index: 9;*/
}

.video-bg-boxes {
  position: relative;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  /*top: 0;*/
  /*left: 0;*/
  /*right: 0;*/
  /*bottom: 0;*/
  padding: 70px 10%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.video-bg-boxes .blue-box {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #0091cf!important;
  padding: 30px 30px 80px 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.video-bg-boxes .blue-box strong {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.video-bg-boxes .blue-box:hover {
  background-color: #E4E1E0!important;
  color: #4C4145!important;
}

.video-bg-boxes .blue-box:hover strong {
  color: #0091CF!important;
}

.video-bg-boxes .blue-box a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.video-bg-boxes .blue-box:hover a {
  color: #0091CF;
}

.video-bg-boxes .grey-box {
  border: none!important;
  padding: 30px 30px 80px 30px;
  background: url("https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3372283/axon-active/img/p1/blue-arrow-ico.png");
  background-position: center 90%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: #E4E1E0;
  color: #4C4145!important;
}

.video-bg-boxes .grey-box strong {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #0091CF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.video-bg-boxes .grey-box:hover {
  background: url("https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3372283/axon-active/img/p1/arrow-ico.png")!important;
  background-position: center 90%!important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
  background-color: #0091cf!important;
  color: #ffffff!important;
}

.video-bg-boxes .grey-box:hover strong {
  color: #ffffff!important;
}

.video-bg-boxes .grey-box a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4C4145;
}

.video-bg-boxes .grey-box:hover a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-module">
  <div class="video-bg-container">
    <div class="video-bg">
      <video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" controls="controls" width="100%" height="100%">
            <source src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3372283/axon-active/img/p1/VerseQuence%20-%20Wilt%20(VOEZ%20Official%20Soundtrack)%20-%20YouTube.mp4?t=1496825800724" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>

    <div class="video-bg-boxes">
      <div class="blue-box">
        <div style="text-align: center;"><strong>Title</strong></div>
        <div style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed condimentum enim eu finibus tincidunt. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent eget neque scelerisque, molestie turpis sed,
          tristique turpis. Proin placerat pretium libero, at pellentesque lorem condimentum eu.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="blue-box">
        <div style="text-align: center;"><strong>Title</strong></div>
        <div style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed condimentum enim eu finibus tincidunt. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent eget neque scelerisque, molestie turpis sed,
          tristique turpis. Proin placerat pretium libero, at pellentesque lorem condimentum eu.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="blue-box">
        <div style="text-align: center;"><strong>Title</strong></div>
        <div style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed condimentum enim eu finibus tincidunt. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent eget neque scelerisque, molestie turpis sed,
          tristique turpis. Proin placerat pretium libero, at pellentesque lorem condimentum eu.</div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: The height of video does not scale with the blue boxes. Can you fix it?